# How to use @font-face for the Manrope font?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I need to use a custom font in my email templates and `@font-face` looks like the only viable option.

In the previous version of the template there was ProximaNova

```
@font-face {
    font-family: ProximaNova;
    src: url(https://cdn.auth0.com/fonts/proxima-nova/proximanova-regular-webfont-webfont.eot);
    src: url(https://cdn.auth0.com/fonts/proxima-nova/proximanova-regular-webfont-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), url(https://cdn.auth0.com/fonts/proxima-nova/proximanova-regular-webfont-webfont.woff) format('woff');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal
}

@font-face {
    font-family: ProximaNova;
    src: url(https://cdn.auth0.com/fonts/proxima-nova/proximanova-semibold-webfont-webfont.eot);
    src: url(https://cdn.auth0.com/fonts/proxima-nova/proximanova-semibold-webfont-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), url(https://cdn.auth0.com/fonts/proxima-nova/proximanova-semibold-webfont-webfont.woff) format('woff');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal
}
```

Now I need to replace it with Manrope https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Manrope?sidebar.open=true&selection.family=Manrope but there is no instructions how to use it in `@font-face`.

Comment: At the page you linked, there's an "Embed" tab at the upper right. You can click this to see two more tabs for `@import`- and `<link>`-style font inclusion as well as brief code showing how to make use of them.

Comment: @Ouroborus yes, but there is no tab for `@font-face`

Comment: That's because you don't need to do that yourself. You replace that with the `@import` Google provides which will import, into your CSS, a generated CSS file that contains the needed `@font-face` declarations designed for optimal compatibility. Or you can use the provided `<style>` to load that file in your HTML instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the `Manrope` font family zip from google, extract the `Manrope-VariableFont_wght.ttf` file and place it in you css folder.
Then in your stylesheet simply add:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'manrope';
    src: url('Manrope-VariableFont_wght.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: How can I use local font file in email template?

Comment: ah ok sorry, I had not noticed this.
So if you don't want to use the import directive, or it doesn't work within your email template, you could host the desired ttf in a web space you have access to, and then pass it as link in the src url() css syntax